# Access Firefox tabs (underlined) keyboard shortcuts

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

In Firefox (currently 58.0.2 as of this post) a right click on a tab brings up the tab menu, where all the entries have an underlined (I believe it's called an "Accelerator") character: **R**eload Tab, **M**ute Tab, etc.

But since they're not in a "proper" menu bar entry with its own "Accelerator" key, I fail to see how one could, specifically, access the "Move to New **W**indow" function using *just* the keyboard..?

Answer (score 0):

1. Focus the "Location" input field (somehow also called [address-bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-web-address-bar#w_web-search-in-the-address-bar)) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (or <kbd>F6</kbd>) ;
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> 2 times to focus the (active) tab ;
3. Press [the "menu" key](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-key-menu.html.en) ;
4. Press <kbd>w</kbd>.

Quite a handful, if someone has got a better way, please come forward.